# How to share the BUILD_NUMBER between jobs with Hudson

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

I have separated a big Hudson job into smaller jobs. Job A does the main build and Job B does another build with a different configuration. I have configured Hudson, so that the A triggers B and that works fine, the problem is that Job A has the original build number and B has started from 1.

My question is: Is it possible to pass the BUILD_NUMBER environment variable somehow from Job A to Job B? The build number is used in the build artifact names, hence it would be nice to have the numbers match between artifacts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Use the parametrized [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org//display/HUDSON/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin), which will allow you to pass the build number from A to B. You will not be able to actually set the build number in job B, but you will have the build number from A to generate your version number.

If you want to synchronize the build number, you can edit the file `nextBuildNumber` in the job directory to match the number from job A. Be aware that these numbers will drift apart over the time since when A fails B will not be started.

**EDIT** I just stumbled across the [Next Build Number Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org//display/HUDSON/Next+Build+Number+Plugin). Have a look, If this one helps you.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I managed to the the BUILD_NUMBER passed to B from A pretty much as has been documented on the plugin front page. BUILD_NUMBER=${BUILD_NUMBER}. The env variable is the same in both projects.

Comment: Editing the nextBuildNumber file didn't seem to have any effect, my changes are always overwritten. I can avoid the numbers being out of sync by triggering B even if A fails. That ofcourse makes B fail as well.

Comment: The scenario is: A is successful, changes the nextBuildNumber-file and than needs to force Hudson to reload the configuration. This only needs to be done if A fails. If A doesn't fail, I am not sure if Hudson will reload the confif if another process runs.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at the plug-in.